# MySQL database query INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I want to insert data in to a MySQL database table called furesz. What do I need to add to my query so that I can insert `M-001` in to the machine column ?

so far I have come with My code **:**

```
INSERT INTO furesz (wood, cubic, width, machine) 
SELECT wood, cubic, width
FROM kobolo
WHERE wood = 'oak' AND width = '0.30' AND length = '0.12'
```

Result:

| machine | wood | cubic | width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | oak | 0.12 | 0.30 |

Comment: `INSERT INTO furesz (wood, cubic, width, machine) 
SELECT wood, cubic, width, machine
FROM kobolo
WHERE wood = 'oak' AND width = '0.30' AND length = '0.12'`

Comment: Is 'M-001' a dynamic value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a fix value, you can simply add it to the query:

```
INSERT INTO furesz (wood, cubic, width, machine) 
SELECT wood, cubic, width, 'M-001'
FROM kobolo
WHERE wood = 'oak' AND width = '0.30' AND length = '0.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
INSERT INTO furesz (wood, cubic, width, machine) 
    SELECT 'oak', cubic, '0.30', 'M-001'
    FROM kobolo
    WHERE wood = 'oak' AND width = '0.30' AND length = '0.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

or, maybe you can try :

```
INSERT INTO furesz (wood, cubic, width, machine) 
SELECT wood, cubic, width, machine
FROM kobolo
WHERE machine = 'M-001' wood = 'oak' AND width = '0.30' AND length = '0.12'
```